# Quarkus: IllegalStateException: Unable to construct the type handle for CLASS bean

Tags: java, jpa, generics, quarkus

I am running the quarkus application using `mvn compile quarkus:dev` and getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to construct the type handle for CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.dao.DaoManager<T extends org.acme.entities.IEntity, I extends java.io.Serializable>, java.lang.Object, org.acme.dao.IDao<T extends org.acme.entities.IEntity, I extends java.io.Serializable>], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.dao.DaoManager]: Unsupported bean type: UNRESOLVED_TYPE_VARIABLE, I
```

I have made a generic DAO class that implements a generic Interface IDAO, IDAO accepts only JPA entity marked with T extends IEntity
(note: I extends Serializable!)
Bean is marked with ApplicationScoped because include @Inject EntityManager
:

```
import org.acme.entities.IEntity;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DaoManager<T extends IEntity<I>, I extends Serializable> implements IDao<T,I> {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public <T> void save(T entity){
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
}

public interface IEntity<I extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
}

public interface IDao<T extends IEntity<I>, I extends Serializable> {

    <T> void save(T entity);

}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I think here an entity manager producer is missing.

Comment: @GiorgioD. can you suggest me an example?

Comment: Something like this:                             `public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceContext    
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your class has several unknown types for Quarkus and as the result, it cannot make an object out of it.

You can define producer for DaoManagers with your interested entity, then Quarkus is able to create objects.

Comment: can you suggest me an example? Thanks

Comment: you mean like https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/java-ee-cdi-producer-methods-tutorial.html ?